# How to determine if a CultureInfo instance supports Latin characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, cultureinfo

Is it possible to determine if the [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) instance that I am working with is based on a Latin character set or not?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can use the `CultureInfo.TextInfo.ANSICodePage`.
There are only so many of these (detailed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964654).

You mostly just need to check that it's value is either 1252 or 1250

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is sufficient, but how about testing the CultureInfo.NativeName property for Latin characters using the [CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a91e3zb6.aspx) method

See also the [Unicode UAX #24 on Script Properties](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/) and the [Unicode Character to Script](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt) assignment table.