# Is there an enum type for letters in .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, enums, base-class-library

I need enum type that defines letters for using in a project. Is there such an enum type in .NET framework ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572963/why-we-cant-have-char-enum-types

The short answer is "no", but letters are also known as CHAR, which is a number. So you can pretty much work with char directly instead of enums.

Comment: Note that an enum by default uses a `System.Int32` as backing. You can interprete that as a UTF-32 encoded Unicode code-point (most of the values are outside the Unicode range, of course, but that is no problem). Note that the `char` struct ([`System.Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char.aspx)) has static methods `ConvertFromUtf32` and `ConvertToUtf32` that you can use. If all your Unicode characters are in the [BMP (plane 0)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane) it is even easier: Just cast to and from `char`. Beware of normalization, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that there's no enum available, a quick way to generate an enumerable (IEnumerable of Char) that contains all the letters of a character set is...

```
 var letters = Enumerable.Range(0, 255).Select(Convert.ToChar).Where(Char.IsLetter);
```

You can 'or' the method group with IsDigit or IsPunctuation to include additional letters.

Note:  there are limitations and assumptions to this approach. Check these...

> The Unicode characters are divided into categories. A character's
>   category is one of its properties. For example, a character might be
>   an uppercase letter, a lowercase letter, a decimal digit number, a
>   letter number, a connector punctuation, a math symbol, or a currency
>   symbol. The UnicodeCategory class returns the category of a Unicode
>   character. For more information on Unicode characters, see the Unicode
>   Standard.

Source:  [How to determine if a CultureInfo instance supports Latin characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127277/how-to-determine-if-a-cultureinfo-instance-supports-latin-characters)

> The .NET Framework uses the Char structure to represent a Unicode
>   character. The Unicode Standard identifies each Unicode character with
>   a unique 21-bit scalar number called a code point, and defines the
>   UTF-16 encoding form that specifies how a code point is encoded into a
>   sequence of one or more 16-bit values. Each 16-bit value ranges from
>   hexadecimal 0x0000 through 0xFFFF and is stored in a Char structure.
>   The value of a Char object is its 16-bit numeric (ordinal) value.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Char(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm Japanese. This code generated none of the characters in my native character set.

Answer (score 6):

Which of the hundreds of alphabets in common use in the world did you have in mind?  Which is the rub of course.

The worst problem is that even in languages that adopted the same alphabet, the letter order isn't the same.  The Danes put the å first instead of last for example.  Crippling properties for an enum, it is *impossible* to come up with an enum that can represent an alphabet.  Unless it is a really obscure one that is used in only one small part of the world or your program doesn't travel very far.  Pretty unlikely in the Internet age.

Make sure you don't try, keep it `char`.  And never overlook the need for System.StringComparison

Comment: The order (collation) might not be relevant to his use. (Even ASCII characters can have different collation in different cultures, for example West Frisian puts `Y` near `I`, and Estonian puts `Z` near `S`.) Any unicode character can fit very easily into an `Int32` (via UTF-32). Of course Unicode normalization will be an issue.

Comment: I was born there :)  Y is actually a ligature for IJ.  And is normally written with a diaeresis, Ÿ.

Comment: That shows how complex things are. However [Lithuanian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithuanian_alphabet) also puts `Y` near `I`, and I don't think their `Y` is identical to the `IJ` of Dutch and Frisian. Now, I am Dane :-) and we do put `Å` last, our last three letters being `Æ-Ø-Å`. However Swedish has the order `Å-Ä-Ö` at the end of its alphabet.